# How to control IOS A2DP silence transmission after AVRCP pause?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

My team is implementing a Bluetooth speaker.  We test the product with both IOS and Android sources.  IOS sources always transmit A2DP silence for about 8 seconds after pausing music playback, initiated either locally at the iPhone or by remotely with an AVRCP pause command.  That 8 second post-play silence interval is causing us application difficulties (over-the-air Bluetooth data capacity problems).

Ideally we'd like to slam close the silence transmission after pause.  Our best hope to solve the problem has been to send a GAVD suspend command after pause.  It does immediately stop silence transmission but it also causes the iPhone to send sporadic A2DP signalling events (specifically a several second delayed stream start which is also incorrect).

Does anyone know of a gentler way to control A2DP silence transmissions from an iPhone after pausing music playback?